# Random value placement in matrix in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have a table of `type array(1 TO 4, 1 TO 4) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);`

This table contains a series of numbers between 0 and 16:

```
0 2  0  2 
2 2  4  4
8 8  16 16
8 16 16 16
```

I want to generate randomly a 2 or 4 into one of the cells containing a zero. (These are in pos 1,1 and 1,3 now but could be anywhere). This is not a static situation.
I have tried to solve this problem by iterating over the array and adding the positions to a new array but that doesn't seem to be the VHDL way and it doesn't synthesise. Also apparently the modulus operator can't work with dynamic inputs. After generating the random values I sum the values in L/R/U/D modus and start again.

```
cnt := 1;
FOR i IN 1 TO 4 LOOP
    FOR j IN 1 TO 4 LOOP
        IF (myTable(i,j) = "0000") THEN
            myEmptyFlags(cnt,1) <= i;
            myEmptyFlags(cnt,2) <= j;
            cnt:=cnt+1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;

res :=(conv_integer(randomValue(3 downto 0)) MOD cnt)+1;

IF (conv_integer(randomValue(3 downto 1)) > 3) THEN
    --put 2 in cell nr res
    myTable(myEmptyFlags(res,1),myEmptyFlags(res,2)) <= "0001";
ELSE 
    --put 4 in cell nr res
    myTable(myEmptyFlags(res,1),myEmptyFlags(res,2)) <= "0010";
END IF;
nextstate <= st_end;
```

What would be a correct VHDL solution for this problem?

Comment: you're implementing the 2048 game in vhdl, aren't you?

Comment: yes I am :) Do you have any ideas?

Comment: on vhdl I'm a beginner as well.. Sorry, I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is nothing like a random number generator in HDL which would be synthesizable. There are only pseudorandom ones. As a good pseudorandom generator you can use for example a non-initialised SRAM memory on your development board. By reading out data one by one you will obtain pseudorandom values.

Other methods are based for example on Game of Life-like principles.

Also use the parallelism of FPGA platform. You've got 16 registers so you can make a 16bit long vector which says there is/isn't 0 at the given cell. This can be done very easily asynchronously. Then you can take a "random" number and look at the position which it represents (let say lower 4bits represents all 16 cells). If there will be a 0 at the given address you can put 2 or 4 in the place based on the last bit of the number. If not, you can iterate through cells starting this one and assign the random number to the first empty cell. If the algorithm iterates the whole 16 cells, then it means the game is over. Everything can be performed in like 2-18 clock cycles.

Comment: Thx! I do not need a real random generator of course, I'm using a pseudo random generator based on a a shift register and xor. I did also think of this solution, I skipped it because I tough maybe it isn't as good as it could be.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to dynamically select a number of bits from a random STD_LOGIC_VECTOR? By this I mean, count the number of 0000 in the table and than depending on that number select only x bits in the random vector?

Comment: I suppose, that your hardware contains embedded block RAMs. So you can use one of these. Pre-initialise it by hand by "pseudorandom" values and then use it. It will provide you the necessary addresses for assigning the 2s and 4s randomly to the array.

Comment: Yes you can count the number of same bits in the vector. Try searching Hamming distance calculation.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing the loop for iterating trough the cells if the cell from the random generator is not empty, what do you think is the best way?

Comment: You need to check only 16 cells, therefore I would suggest a simple finite state machine with 16 states in loop. In some signal, you can note the initial state of the machine given by the random generator and iterate until you reach again this state. This would be implemented in a way like: `state <= next_state when next_state /= initial_state else exit;` So you need only like 18 states: init, states 1 to 16, exit. Or one more state for distinguishing easily between exit(loop closure = game over) and number_assigned.